# Discord.py - Ban everyone in the server without a role

Tags: permissions, bots, discord, discord.py

I was messing around with the ban everyone command, trying to fix it so it actually does something instead of giving me the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

The problem is that I don't know how to exclude the administrator roles and ban members without a role (only pingable with @everyone). The code I am currently using:

```
@client.command()
async def e(ctx):
    print('Logged in!')
    for member in client.get_all_members():
        await member.ban(reason=banreason + banreason2 + banreason3)
        await ctx.send(f"**{member.display_name}** was banned and invite links were sent. :white_check_mark:")
        print(f"Banned {member.display_name} and invite links were sent.")
    print("Banning is complete!")
```

Note: there is no error with banreason, it works fine and has nothing to do with the permission error.
I also put the bot above the roles I want to be banned.

Comment: Put some prints in before calling `ban`, to see who it's failing on.  You'll always fail to ban the server owner, as they cannot be banned from their own server.  You can catch the exception and just `continue` to the next member.

Comment: The print showed me that it was the staff team that triggered the error. I'm not sure how to handle the exception correctly, since I got some Indent Expected error within the try/except bracket. But I got this bot working now. Thanks for taking your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to exclude everyone that has a role other than @everyone than the following will work.

```
@client.command()
async def e(ctx):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if len(member.roles) < 2:
            await member.ban(reason=banreason + banreason2 + banreason3)
            await ctx.send(f"**{member.display_name}** was banned and invite links were sent. :white_check_mark:")
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name} and invite links were sent.")
    print("Banning complete!")
```

Comment: And if for some reason your serverowner does not have another role change the if statement to:

```if len(member.roles) < 2 and member != ctx.guild.owner:```

Comment: Thanks very much! The whole useless server is being wiped out now. Appreciate the help!